# How to access an array of objects which is a key-value pair

Tags: javascript

i want to access the id 'qwsa221' without using array index but am only able to reach and output all of the array elements not a specific element.

i have tried using filter but couldnt figure out how to use it properly.

```
 let lists = {
      def453ed: [
        {
          id: "qwsa221",
          name: "Mind"
        },
        {
          id: "jwkh245",
          name: "Space"
        }
      ]
    };
```

Comment: could you share your filter try so we can see what you've done and correct you on this one ?

Comment: const result = boardId.filter(id => id== 'qwsa221');
console.log(result);
//where boardId is reffered as 'def453ed'

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.keys()` to get all the keys of the object and check the values in the array elements using . notation

```js
let lists = {
  def453ed: [{
      id: "qwsa221",
      name: "Mind"
    },
    {
      id: "jwkh245",
      name: "Space"
    }
  ]
};
Object.keys(lists).forEach(function(e) {
  lists[e].forEach(function(x) {
    if (x.id == 'qwsa221')
      console.log(x)

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this, using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
 let lists = {
  def453ed: [
    {
      id: "qwsa221",
      name: "Mind"
    },
    {
      id: "jwkh245",
      name: "Space"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(
  lists.def453ed // first get the array
  .find(         // find return the first entry where the callback returns true
    el => el.id === "qwsa221"
  )
)
```

here's a corrected version of your filter :

```js
let lists = {def453ed: [{id: "qwsa221",name: "Mind"},{id: "jwkh245",name: "Space"}]};

// what you've done
const badResult = lists.def453ed.filter(id => id === "qwsa221");
/*
here id is the whole object
{
  id: "qwsa221",
  name: "Mind"
}
*/
console.log(badResult)

// the correct way
const goodResult = lists.def453ed.filter(el => el.id === "qwsa221");
console.log(goodResult)

// filter returns an array so you need to actually get the first entry
console.log(goodResult[0])
```

Comment: This solution will work specifically for the given data, if there are more than 1 key present it will fail.

Comment: @ellipsis true ! but since the question is not clear on this point we don't if there is the possibility of another key

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `Object.Keys` method to iterate through all of the keys present.
2. You can also use `filter`, if there are multiple existence of id `qwsa221`

```js
let lists = {
      def453ed: [
        {
          id: "qwsa221",
          name: "Mind"
        },
        {
          id: "jwkh245",
          name: "Space"
        }
      ]
    };

let l = Object.keys(lists)
  .map(d => lists[d]
  .find(el => el.id === "qwsa221"))
  
  console.log(l)
```